# Boolean algebra with 5 sets

Tags: boolean-algebra

Simplify the following Boolean expression. Your final equation should be in minimized sum-of-products form.

W = B' (A + BC + B'CD + A'D)

So far I have:

Use distributing:

AB' + B'BC + B'B'CD + A'B'D

Complementary:

AB' + 0 + B'B'CD + A'B'D

Is this right so far? What's next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far so good.

Next,
\begin{align}
AB' + B'CD + A'B'D
&= B'(A + CD + A'D)\\
&= B'(A + (A+A')CD + A'D)\\
&= B'((A+ACD) + (A'CD + A'D))\\
&= B'(A + A'D)\tag{Absortion laws}\\
&= B'((A+A')(A+D))\tag{Distributivity}\\
&= B'(A+D).
\end{align}
I suppose that the equalities that I didn't justify are quite immediate.

**Edit.**
In sum of products, just distribute again, to get $AB' + B'D$.